# Tool to recursively search all files in a directory for a string

Tags: windows, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to search for strings inside files without indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317944/tools-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-without-indexing)

Before I make one, any good tools out there for free/cheap that will recurse through all files in a directory and search for a text string in them? Need to find an instance of a string in any configuration files laying around.

Kind of like a Windows Search "find files that contain..." on steroids?

**Oops - This is pretty much a duplicate question, sorry, didn't find the other one before**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317944/tools-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-without-indexing