# find function in MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, function, locate

I would need to find all the places in my code (several M files in a folder) where I used a particular function (`unique` in this case).

Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to recursively search all files in a directory for a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266796/tool-to-recursively-search-all-files-in-a-directory-for-a-string) or an older version with better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317944/tools-to-search-for-strings-inside-files-without-indexing

Comment: If the `Matlab` tag is meaningful, then these are not exact duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Matlab, there is the command "Find Files" - in the "Edit" menu, or on the "Home" and "Editor" ribbon - that allows you to find files containing specific text, either in a folder or on the entire Matlab path:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the "find in files" function in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check what functions you're using, `depfun` allows you to do so, although it might be overkill if you only want to check for a single known function.

For example (checking functions called directly by a function only):

```
[list builtins] = depfun(fun, '-toponly');
```

Answer (score 0):

"which" seems to do it.

Take a look at this: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/which.html (1st example)

Otherwise, notepad++ allows you to search (and replace) multiple files for a text string, here's a simple tutorial:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/

Comment: `which` only allows you to find functions, not instances inside files where specific functions are called.